# An error occurred while instantiating class. Need help in resolving issue

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing an error in instantiating the class when I try to run by test case. I have defined values in config file and then read the value file in read property file and set up webdriver in base file and finally run my test cases by extending based. However it keeps on throwing the below error message.

```
ERROR:
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.8.0
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See ``http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder`` for further details.
org.testng.TestNGException:
An error occurred while instantiating class testcases.FirstTestFrame. Check to make sure it can be instantiated
at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:113)
at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:40)
at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:28)
at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:106)
at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:136)
at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:129)
at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:109)
at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:101)
at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:66)
at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:483)
at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:356)
at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:309)
at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:228)
at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG7_8$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG7_8.java:34)
at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG7_8$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG7_8.java:67)
at org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:720)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:224)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:116)
at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1375)
at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1349)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1191)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

---

---

Below is the
**config file:**

```
browser =chrome
url = ``http://some`` sample url
```

---

Below is the read file created to ready property values

**Read property file:**

```
package utilities;

import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Properties;

public class ReadpropertyFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

FileReader fr = new FileReader("Configfiles\\config.properties");
    
    
    Properties p = new Properties();
    
    p.load(fr);
    
    System.out.println(p.getProperty("browser"));
    System.out.println(p.getProperty("testurl"));

}
```

---

**BASE FILE:**

```
Below is the base file created to set up webdriver manager
```

```
import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.time.Duration; 
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
 import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest; 
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class BaseTest { 
public static WebDriver driver ; 
public static Properties prop = new Properties(); 
public static FileReader fr ; 
public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));

@BeforeTest 
public void setUp() throws IOException  {
    if (driver==null) {
        
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Configfiles\\config.properties");
        
        prop.load(fr);
}
    
    if(prop.getProperty("browser").equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("testurl"));
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }else if(prop.getProperty("browser").equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {
        WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
        driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.get(prop.getProperty("testurl"));;
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    
}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown()  {
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.close();
    System.out.println("Application closed successfully");
}
}
```

---

**Test Case: FirstTestFrame:** This is the test cases when I run facing the issue

```
public class FirstTestFrame extends BaseTest {

WebDriverWait wait;

public FirstTestFrame(WebDriver driver) {

    this.driver = driver;
    this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, null);        
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

public void initialisingDriver() {
    
    launchApp();
}
@Test
public static void LaunchAppClickWizard() throws InterruptedException {
    


    // driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    WebElement caseMenu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("")));

    action.moveToElement((WebElement) caseMenu).build().perform();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

}
```